# Whenever I try installing something from the software center it always says 'requires installation of untrusted packages'

Tags: software-center, playonlinux

I am using software server 12.04 but whenever I try installing something like playonlinux for example it says **Requires installation of untrusted packages** and when i click details it gives me:

```
fonts-droid fonts-horai-umefont fonts-unfonts-core gnome-exe-thumbnailer icoutils     
libcapi20-3 libmpg123-0 libpam-winbind libwbclient0 mesa-utils playonlinux 
python-wxgtk2.8 python-wxversion samba-common smbclient ttf-droid ttf-umefont 
ttf-unfonts-core winbind wine wine-gecko1.4 wine1.4 wine1.4-common wine1.4-i386 winetricks
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like an issue with the GPG signing keys that are used to sign packages from repositories.

One possibility is that the software repository you are connecting to is out of date (by a significant amount eg weeks).  In Software Sources try selecting a different server.  "Server for United States" will always be a reliable one.

(I'm assuming you're doing this via the desktop interface and not the console)